# Merging multiple Eloquent models keeping newest one but filling out blank attributes with other model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Lets say I've got 3 Eloquent models which I want to merge to one model.

The newest model should be the base model, from which I want to fill blank attributes with the (possible) data from the other two models.

So:

```
id | created_at | name     | location | favorite_piza | drink | pet
5  | 2018-03-22 | John Doe |          |               | Beer  |
2  | 2017-02-12 | John Doe | Earth    | Hawai         |       |
1  | 2012-01-01 | J. Doe   |          | Margarita     |       | Dog
```

Result:

```
5 | 2018-03-22 | John Doe  | Earth    | Hawai         | Beer  | Dog
```

Off course I could loop through all the known attributes and traverse each not-newest model to see if the attribute is set...

But that sounds a little bit cumbersome; there should be a better way to aggregate these models to one, with the newest as base.

Comment: Are the blank attributes `NULL` or an empty string?

Comment: That depends on the column.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution I can think of:

```
$result = $models->first();
$attributes = ['name', 'location', 'favorite_piza', 'drink', 'pet'];
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    $values = $models->pluck($attribute)->filter(function($value) {
        return !is_null($value) && $value !== '';
    });
    $result->$attribute = $values->first();
}
```

If you know for sure that non of [these values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) can appear in your data, you can simplify the filtering:

```
$result->$attribute = $models->pluck($attribute)->filter()->first();
```